# PHP if statement shortcut

Tags: php, arrays, variables, loops, if-statement

I have a script that is importing data from a csv source.  Many of the fields/columns are in "code."  For example, the school field is a numeric number apposed to the actual school name.  I need to convert the code into the actual name before it imports into the db.

My question is, is there a quicker way to do this conversion other than using a "if" statement.  Some of the fields that need to be converted have 20+ options so i am wondering if there is another way to write the conversion instead of having 20 if statments.  Right now I have:

```
if($data['school'] = 0001) {$school = "school1"; } 
if($data['school'] = 0002) {$school = "school2"; }
if($data['school'] = 0003) {$school = "school3"; }...

or i could use if else statements
```

So my question is:  Is there a quicker way either through some sort of array or loop or other type of php statement that I could speed up this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have all of this in a file, or do you have to type it into PHP code by hand either way?

You can put the code mappings into an associative array, then a single statement will get the right name.

```
$schoolCodeToName = array(
    '0001' => 'school1',
    '0002' => 'school2',
    '0003' => 'school3'
    // ...
);

$school = $schoolCodeToName[ $data['school'] ];
```

If you want to save yourself from the typing, then you need some code to load a data file and build the `$schoolCodeToName` array.

Answer (score 4):

would

```
  $school = 'school' . (int)$data['school'];
```

work?

Comment: Alternatively: `$data['school'] += 0`